# Columns resizing in 'angular-scrollable-table'

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm working with  'angular-scrollable-table' because it has fixed-headers:
[GitHub](https://github.com/alalonde/angular-scrollable-table).

How can I use 'resizable' directive?

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? Perhaps it would be best to contact the author of the package for documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Just add the attribute resizable:

```
<scrollable-table resizable>
```

Comment: A sample code would be a lot more relevant in order to answer the question.